# Debug Cocoa library method

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

Is there a way to step into a Cocoa library method to see the assembly or implementation? I've been trying to debug the NSEvent method [touchesMatchingPhase](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSEvent/touchesMatchingPhase:inView:), but when I try to step into it Xcode it jumps over it. Does xcode restrict stepping into library methods? Is it possible to inspect the implementation?

Comment: What exactly are you doing "when [you] try to step into it"? If you haven't already, try the "si" command at the console prompt.

Comment: Can you read assembler?

Comment: Ok, after using the si command a few time it takes me to objc_msgSend which has a jump statement to touchesMatchingPhase assembly implementation. I'm able to step to the jump statement and see the method's implementation. Do you know if there is a way to decompile the implementation's assembly instructions to C or something more human readable?

Comment: [Class dump](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/) ended up having what I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no restriction as such, but you'll only see the assembler. To enter a library method or function:

1. In your source code place a breakpoint on the call.
2. Run
3. When the breakpoint is hit hold the the control key and press the step into button. The control key indicates you wish to do the operation by the machine instruction rather than the source code line, the debugger step etc. button icons will change to show a dot under them. The program will stop again on exactly the same line, this is because it takes a few machine instructions - number depends on the number and kind of parameters you are passing - before you actually enter the method/function.
4. Repeat the control + click until you enter the method/function - as soon as you enter the method/function the debugger will switch to showing you assembler as it does not have the source code.
5. Once you are in a method/function without source there is no need to hold the control key down when clicking the buttons, the icons will change to show a dot under them and stay that way until you enter a method/function with source.

If you wish to see the assembler for instructions stepped over in (3) & (4) you can select `Debug -> Debug Workflow -> Show Disassembly When Debugging` at any time to *always* show assembler rather than source.

HTH