# What happed when we excute NSTimer invalidate?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstimer

```
self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(timeCall:) userInfo:self.strong repeats:YES];
[self.timer invalidate];
NSLog(@"%p",[self.timer userInfo]);
```

Then app crashes because `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Apple document says,

`This method is the only way to remove a timer from an NSRunLoop object. The NSRunLoop object removes its strong reference to the timer, either just before the invalidate method returns or at some later point. If it was configured with target and user info objects, the receiver removes its strong references to those objects as well.`

And Apple tells us not to use `userInfo` after a timer invalidate.But why?

The timer's refrence count is controlled by programmer,and also the userInfo(I tried use property as userInfo,instead of using constant string),the result is the same.

If we put a symbol breakpoint like `-[NSTimer userinfo]`,we can get crash info like

```
CoreFoundation`-[__NSCFTimer userInfo]:
    0x7fff20384d32 <+0>:  pushq  %rbp
    0x7fff20384d33 <+1>:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x7fff20384d36 <+4>:  pushq  %rbx
    0x7fff20384d37 <+5>:  subq   $0x38, %rsp
    0x7fff20384d3b <+9>:  movq   0x5fca7d6e(%rip), %rax    ; (void *)0x00007fff86d060e0: __stack_chk_guard
    0x7fff20384d42 <+16>: movq   (%rax), %rax
    0x7fff20384d45 <+19>: movq   %rax, -0x10(%rbp)
    0x7fff20384d49 <+23>: leaq   -0x38(%rbp), %rbx
    0x7fff20384d4d <+27>: movq   $0x0, (%rbx)
    0x7fff20384d54 <+34>: movq   %rbx, %rsi
    0x7fff20384d57 <+37>: callq  0x7fff203a6ff9            ; CFRunLoopTimerGetContext
    0x7fff20384d5c <+42>: movq   0x8(%rbx), %rax
->  0x7fff20384d60 <+46>: movq   0x18(%rax), %rax
    0x7fff20384d64 <+50>: movq   0x5fca7d45(%rip), %rcx    ; (void *)0x00007fff86d060e0: __stack_chk_guard
    0x7fff20384d6b <+57>: movq   (%rcx), %rcx
    0x7fff20384d6e <+60>: cmpq   -0x10(%rbp), %rcx
    0x7fff20384d72 <+64>: jne    0x7fff20384d7b            ; <+73>
    0x7fff20384d74 <+66>: addq   $0x38, %rsp
    0x7fff20384d78 <+70>: popq   %rbx
    0x7fff20384d79 <+71>: popq   %rbp
    0x7fff20384d7a <+72>: retq   
    0x7fff20384d7b <+73>: callq  0x7fff204c318e            ; symbol stub for: __stack_chk_fail
```

I know the relationship between NSRunloop and NSTimer,but what about this userinfo property?Maybe it's for archiving the `readonly` keyword,I guess.How can we look into the internel implementation of `NSTimer` or is there a way to explore?

Comment: `If it was configured with target and user info objects, the receiver removes its strong references to those objects as well.` so self.timer is nil and there is no reference to userInfo as well.

Comment: as `self.timer` indicates you made a property with `NSTimer`. It is helpful to set the internal `_timer = nil;` right after `[self.timer invalidate];`. It helps re-apply a new NSTimer onto self.timer `if (!_timer) self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:];`

Comment: From the manual I would expect ```userInfo```'s pointer to at worst just return 0 if it was released. Although ```userInfo``` is defined as a property in the header, I suspect from the crash dump that it really is a message with either a polite check that throws that exception or - gasp - a horrible bug. Since it seems the message calls ```CFRunLoopTimerGetContext```, where you need pre-allocated memory, I suppose perhaps maybe it could just be a bug. Still, doing anything with an invalidated timer will not earn any sympathy from the army of bug fixers working on the framework.

Comment: @OlSen,As I edited the question,the timer's refrence count and also the userInfo's,is controlled by programmer.

Comment: You can't call `userInfo` on an invalidated `NSTimer`. Does it matter why? If you want to explore: Call `CFRunLoopTimerGetContext` before and after `invalidate` and explore the context. See also [Debug Cocoa library method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336648/debug-cocoa-library-method).

Comment: @Willeke,Is this a design error?`userInfo` is a property of a timer,I create it,after `invalidate timer`,I can't access it,even both the `timer` and the `userInfo` still exist.

Comment: The `userInfo` property is syntaxic sugar for `-[__NSCFTimer userInfo]`. Apparently `userInfo` is stored inside `info` of the context and `invalidate` deletes this `info`. The timer doesn't have a pointer to the `userInfo` object after `invalidate`.